How to connect sheet symbol with multiplied port with repeated sheet symbol without warnings?
I have a sheet with 16 nets connected to one port:

Now I am tying to connect this sheet symbol to a bus:

And then connect this bus to a port of repeated sheet symbol:

Electrically everything worked. But aside of that I have some validation warnings:

Net element has multiple names:



Net has only one pin (for unused nets, which is fine for me):


I can just ignore the warnings, but I don't like this approach. If it is possible to make them dissapear, I'd be much happier with the project.
Can anyone suggest how do I make these connections better and in mpre correct way?
